# How to stop ImageMagick in Ruby (Rmagick) evaluating an @ sign in text annotation

Tags: ruby, rmagick

In an app I recently built for a client the following code resulted in the variable `@nameText` being evaluated, and then resulting in an error 'no text' (since the variable doesn't exist).

To get around this I used gsub, as per the example below. Is there a way to tell Magick not to evaluate the string at all?

```
require 'RMagick'

@image = Magick::Image.read( '/path/to/image.jpg' ).first
@nameText = '@SomeTwitterUser'
@text = Magick::Draw.new
@text.font_family = 'Futura'
@text.pointsize = 22
@text.font_weight = Magick::BoldWeight

# Causes error 'no text'...
# @text.annotate( @image, 0,0,200,54, @nameText )

@text.annotate( @image, 0,0,200,54, @nameText.gsub('@', '\@') )
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the variable inside of the string?

Comment: The @nameText variable is actually a param sent by the user. They create a billboard image featuring their twitter profile pic and twitter name.

Comment: I think you want this `"#{@SomeTwitterUser}"`

Comment: By the way, you are violating Ruby naming conventions. [See the Style Guide](https://github.com/styleguide/ruby). They should be `@name_text ` and `@some_twitter_user`

Comment: @screenmutt I think you are missing the point. `@SomeTwitterUser` is the Twitter username... not an instance variable. I think you might have made the same mistake as Rmagick here. =)

Comment: Have you tried `"` instead of `'`?

Comment: I get same problem. Note you don't need to use an escape character, any first character other than `@` seems to stop RMagick evaluating the string. It's almost an undocumented feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the C code from RMagick that is returning the error:

```c
// Translate & store in Draw structure
draw->info->text = InterpretImageProperties(NULL, image, StringValuePtr(text));
if (!draw->info->text)
{
    rb_raise(rb_eArgError, "no text");
}
```

It is the call to `InterpretImageProperties` that is modifying the input text - but it is not Ruby, or a Ruby instance variable that it is trying to reference. The function is defined here in the Image Magick core library: http://www.imagemagick.org/api/MagickCore/property_8c_source.html#l02966

Look a bit further down, and you can see the code:

```c
/* handle a '@' replace string from file */
if (*p == '@') {
   p++;
   if (*p != '-' && (IsPathAccessible(p) == MagickFalse) ) {
     (void) ThrowMagickException(&image->exception,GetMagickModule(),
         OptionError,"UnableToAccessPath","%s",p);
     return((char *) NULL);
   }
   return(FileToString(p,~0,&image->exception));
}
```

In summary, this is a core library feature which will attempt to load text from file (named `SomeTwitterUser` in your case, I have confirmed this -try it!), and your work-around is probably the best you can do.

For efficiency, and minimal changes to input strings, you could rely on the selectivity of the library code and only modify the string if it *starts* with `@`:

```rb
@text.annotate( @image, 0,0,200,54, @name_string.gsub( /^@/, '\@') )
```

Comment: Thanks Neil, that was just so bizarre I had to share it.